# Give some links or source code of Line chart which is embedded into application

Tags: android

I want to add line chart in my application , which has two view 1st view is image 2nd view is line chart, i want to add x values dynamically chart has to grow after adding each x values.
please suggest some link or code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Jonas's [GrapView](http://www.jjoe64.com/p/graphview-library.html) lib to show charts. Take a look on this lib, it very simple and easy to use. He shows ho to use it with a lot of example.

Good Luck!

Comment: Ok i got it, but how to set horizontal and vertical labels,  from 0 to 20 for both x and y axis. In GrapView lib example, Simple Graph in 1st linear layout1 example how to set labels. and Dynamically how add new values to existing one ex (new GraphViewData(0,2);)

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand the issue of 2 views in the question. What should the image represent ? How is it related to the chart ?

As for rest (i.e. having a dynamic line chart) - I have successfully achieved that with the AndroidPlot library (http://androidplot.com/), and I think it might do the trick for you.

Comment: In my app i'm continuously getting score, after each iteration i want to add it in text view as well as i have to show in line chart. of particular person image below. for that reason i need both view

Comment: The plot drawn with AndroidPlot does not need to take up the whole screen. You may add arbitrary other views beside it using any available standard methods. 

For example - you could take a look at the quick start tutorial (http://androidplot.com/wiki/Quickstart) - in step 3 there is a layout defined in an XML file - you could add text, images and anything else there.

Comment: ok i'm reffering it now thanks. fallow the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258785/line-chart-using-achartengine .i have done with achart engine can you go through it its showing null pointer exception can you?

Comment: I took a look at that question and tried to provide an answer.

Comment: ok. i got the out put android plot. and i want to add x and y axis labels from 0 to 50. and draw line chart. how can i add x and y axis lables